# How to resolve at runtime which Controller method is going to serve the current request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to create a `Filter` that is capable of identifying at runtime which `Controller` method is going to serve the current request, then make some introspection on the method to check for specific `Annotations` and modify the request/response accordingly.

I could build a `Map` at boot time indexing `Controller` methods by the URIs of their respective request mappings, but I guess it would be smarter to use whatever mechanism Spring is already using to perform this resolution.

So the question is two fold:

- How does Spring actually do this? (and how to exploit it)
- And an open question on better ways of doing this than building a `Map` at boot time

Comment: Could you specify a bit more on what you need to do exactly? Why do you need a filter instead of using a `HandlerInterceptor` (which would give you the actual handler(method) concerned).

Comment: Then the `HandlerInterceptor` could make it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about use ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider

```
      ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
    scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(Controller.class));
    for (BeanDefinition beanDefinition : scanner.findCandidateComponents("com.yourPackage.controllers")){
        System.out.println(beanDefinition.getBeanClassName());
    }
```

Here the API http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to build the map at boot time, you can look on how it's done in the DispatcherServlet.
Look at the `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet#getHandler` method.